# Inheritance in PDO

Tags: php, pdo, extends

I'm fairly new to `php` and I've been playing with `PDO`, my question is,
I have a `dbConfig` class in which i set up my `PDO` connection, Then I have a set of classes such as part time student and full time student which extend student.

The examples I see have:

```
$user = new User(DBcon);
```

Setup in the `dbconfig` class.

And then pass the `dbconnection` in the user constructor like so:

```
public function __construct($Db)
{
    $this->con = $Db;
}
```

This works great.

My problem is that my `student` constructor takes in certain arguments like `name`, `number` etc and my part time and full time students extend these and take in extra arguments like number of courses etc.

How can i then inject the `dbCon` as well, as i would need to specify the other arguments in the `dbCon` class?

Comment: Either use a setter (such as `setDbConnection(DBcon $connection)` or move the persistence logic to a dedicated class.

Comment: Separate the task of *saving and retrieving data to/from the database* from the task of *representing one User/Student instance* into separate classes. A `User` doesn't need a database connection, a `UserStorage` does.